# Keep only rows with date January

Tags: r, statistics

I am working with R and with the following Paneldata:

I only want to analyze the rows that have observations for January e.g 192701

Therefore, I want to delete all other rows.

I'd appreciate all advice

Comment: I assume people are down-voting you as did not provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. I will recommend to take a look at this post; [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: I think the question is formed in such a way that you can understand it. If you look at my history, I formed questions perfectly according to protocol and got no answer. So, I prefer to not waste my time on it now. I don't care about downvotes either. Thank you for the advice anyway.

Comment: Others cannot test out their code on your data without retyping it since it was provided as an image and also they can't be sure from only an image that they have exactly what you have which can introduce ambiguities.  If `DF` is a minimal version of your data frame show the output of `dput(DF)` .

Comment: @user9259005, I added my comment in an attempt to help you get a better answer. I doubt most people will look through your posting history. I understand you do not want to wast time. It's in the same spirit I suggested to make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can filter it with `substr`

```
subset(df1, substr(mdate, 5, 6)  == "01")
```

---

Another option is to convert it to Datetime object and the do the `subset`

```
library(data.table) # for `month` or with `lubridate`
subset(df1, month(zoo::as.yearmon(as.character(mdate), "%Y%m")) == 1)
```

or `paste` with 01 to account for the day, convert it to `Date` class, extract the `month` and do the filter

```
subset(df1,  month(as.Date(paste0(mdate, '01'), "%Y%m%d"))==1)
```

Comment: How would I do the opposite? Only considering rows for February to December?

Comment: @user9259005  In that case change the `==` or `!=`

Comment: There is no `month` function in the base of R but `cycle(as.yearmon(...))` would get the month.

Comment: Could you also tell me how to delete all rows if they have a ST_t1 value of <0 ?